# Can't open Foxit in Ubuntu / Mint Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, 64-bit, linux-mint, foxit-reader

After installing Foxit PDF reader on Ubuntu or Mint Linux, any attempts to open Foxit reader result in absolutely nothing. Foxit simply doesn't open, and provides no useful error messages to indicate what went wrong.

This problem occurs with `FoxitReader_1.1.0_i386.deb` and `FoxitReader_1.0-1_i386.deb` as downloaded directly off the [Foxit website](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/desklinux/download.php).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the Foxit package for Linux is 32-bit only, and won't work on a 64-bit Linux system without some additional libraries. This can be fixed easily in Ubuntu or Mint Linux by installing the 32-bit compatibility libraries from the console like this:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Or alternatively, if that doesn't work, try:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch
```